# Create site collection or web application for my site in SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

I have installed SharePoint 2016 in multi server farm with MinRole architecture and with it the User Profile service Application got Automatically configured. The service application has default **My Site Host URL** as http://spwfe03p-bro:80/my/ :-

[image]

Now my question is that how to create new Web Application or Site Collection as: http://spwfe03p-bro:80**/my/** . I am asking this because if I directly create new site collection under http://spwfe03p-bro:80. It will be something like: http://spwfe03p-bro/sites/my  and not http://spwfe03p-bro:80/my/

Any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

You have first to create a new "managed path" for your Web application:

1. Open the CA
2. Go to the Web applications page
3. Select the Web app "http://spwfe03p-bro:80"
4. From the ribbon, click "managed paths"
5. Add an "Explicit" mmanage path for "my"
6. Then you can go to the site collection creation page to create a new MySite Host collection under /my

Comment: Thanks for reply, but 1 more question. The current sharepoint web application:- http://spwfe03p-bro:80" is already on port 80, ie. its internet facing. Can I create another port 80 web application for my site. If I do that then will both web applications be up and running ?.
Or If not, then if I create a random port web application (say 1335) for My Site, then will that web application be accessible on internet as well?

Comment: The best practice is actually to create a dedicated Web application to host MySites. The new Web application must have either a different URL host (http://XXXX) or a different port. If it's then accessible from the Internet depends on your DNS/reverse-proxy config.